# ActionBar title weight won't be applied

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar, title, android-layout-weight

I'm currently trying to set the font weight of my ActionBar title to bold, with the following code, but it isn't working as expected. What am i doing wrong?

```
<style name="dActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#DDDDDD</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">#000000</item>
    </style>
```

The background color and so on is working pretty well.

Comment: are you using custom font?

Comment: Hello, thank's for your reply. No, just the standard font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not all Android fonts have bold style,for example Chinese words must use setFakeBoldText

```
        final int actionBarTitle = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        final TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().getWindow().findViewById(actionBarTitle);
        title.getPaint().setFakeBoldText(true);
```

Comment: This worked for me. The strange thing is, that the content of the title was just a normal english word. Although it works now :) Thanks!